# NSUserDefaults: Registering Defaults For Dictionary/Array values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

#### The Setup

Suppose my app has an NSDictionary that I store in userDefaults with the key `someDict`. This dictionary looks like this:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

When my app launches, I use `[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` to set the initial value of the `someDict` key to the dictionary above.

Then, my user changes some preferences and this dictionary gets updated so that it now looks like this:

```
key1: someNewValue1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

---

#### The Key Question

I now ship a new version of my app. This new version has a `someDict` with FOUR initial values instead of three:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
key4: someNewValue
```

The userDefaults domain already contains a value for `someDict`, which was set when my user ran the older version of my app. My question is this: does `-registerDefaults` perform a "deep" analysis of NSDictionary and NSArray values?

In other words, is `-registerDefaults` going to detect that `key4` is missing from the old dictionary stored in `someDict`, or is it going to simply say, "There's already a value for `someDict`, so we're done"?

I suspect the latter. Which begs my next question: is there an efficient approach to handling this sort of situation in Cocoa, short of writing my own "registerDefaults" method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "deep" analysis, but I have updated Apps (at the App Store, and for personal use) changing the User Defaults dictionary, and so far, everything seems to work as designed.  I have worked on the assumption that if a new default value appears in my updated dictionary, it is written without any reversion of the values already changed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check the values of `someDict` at startup? If a value is corrupted or somehow contains the wrong information, do you test and correct for this at launch?

My suggestion would be to test if every key is present and the value is valid. If key is not present/valid you simply create/overwrite it.

This can save a lot of pain for users when your app crashes in the middle of updating `someDict`